# Can't decode the date and time Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time, discord.js

I am working with discord.js and Clash Of clans API to make a discord bot.

I made several functions but I can't get 1 to function properly. Here is a Minimal, Reproducible Example
of the code:

```js
const preparationStartTime = "20230422T185511.000Z";
const prepStart = new Date(preparationStartTime.slice(0, -8))

const startTime = "20230423T175511.000Z";
const start = new Date(startTime.slice(0, -8))


const endTime = "20230424T175511.000Z";
const end = new Date(endTime.slice(0, -8));

const prepStartStr = `${prepStart.getDate()}/${prepStart.getMonth() + 1}/${prepStart.getFullYear()} ${prepStart.getHours()} ${prepStart.getMinutes()} ${prepStart.getSeconds()}`;

const startStr = `${start.getDate()}/${start.getMonth() + 1}/${start.getFullYear()} ${start.getHours()} ${start.getMinutes()} ${start.getSeconds()}`;

const endStr = `${end.getDate()}/${end.getMonth() + 1}/${end.getFullYear()} ${end.getHours()} ${end.getMinutes()} ${end.getSeconds()}`;

console.log(`Prep Time: ${prepStartStr} \nStart Time: ${startStr}\nEnd Time: ${endStr}`);
```

Firstly, I used the toISOString() method to convert the dates to string format, which resulted in an incorrect output of NaN/NaN ...
I then tried modifying the code to use the toLocaleString() method instead, but this also produced an incorrect output. Afterwatds, I attempted to replace the T and .000Z substrings in the date strings before parsing them, but this still didn't fix the issue. Finally, I modified the code to use the slice() method to remove the last five characters from the date strings instead of replacing substrings, but this still resulted in an incorrect output.
At this point, i'm still trying to figure out why the output is incorrect and how to fix it.

I tried chatGPT which also tried similar things and i still can't get it to work

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] as formatted text in your question?

Comment: Yeah sure here is a link:

https://pastecode.io/s/zsmi6d7n

Comment: No, not a link to external code. Test in your question. Please focus on **minimal** and **reproducible**. Add values for all variables that come from outside in your real code.

Comment: I edited the question and made the code as simple as possible, If you are going to try it make sure to **npm i request**

Comment: It's Node.js, works fine for me.

Comment: Why are you trying to slice the last 8 characters off that datestring? Why are you trying to slice it at all? It's a valid datestring, but you seem determined to make it *invalid*...

Comment: Can you remove the network request and add the `body` to your question? This question won't help future users when link stops working.

Comment: By removing these characters, we can create a valid JavaScript Date

Comment: No, those are needed to create a valid date, and it isn't clear at all why you're trying to remove them. Javascript `Date.parse` like most languages/databases etc will understand date strings in the [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which yours *already* is (at least from the example in your comment).

Comment: When i use Date.parse() I still get NaN but this time highlighted in yellow meaning its an Integer

Comment: Formats like `20230422T1855` and `20230422T185511.000Z` aren't specified by the specification. Use a specified format or parse the string and use numbers, It's possible that these string work in one browser/engine/version and don't work in another browser/engine/version.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the date strings directly to `Date()` without attempting to `slice()`, and you should receive a proper JavaScript `Date` object in return:

```js
const prepStart = Date(clanwar.preparationStartTime);
```

Testing in the Chrome console, I have no problem with the date strings you are receiving:

```js
Date('20230422T185511.000Z')  // result: 'Wed Apr 26 2023 13:47:59 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)'
```

[EDIT]
To the point made by @jabaa - the date string format you provided does not match the ISO8601 format as required by [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#return_value) or [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse): `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

Just because it works to pass the string of format `YYYYMMDDTHHmmss.sssZ` to `Date()`, it may not be the most portable option.

You can also use the following regular expression to parse out the various date and time fields with named capture groups using [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

`/(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})T(?<hours>\d{2})(?<minutes>\d{2})(?<seconds>\d{2})\.(?<microseconds>\d+)Z/`

For example,

```js
let dateString = '20230426T182700.000Z'

const re = RegExp(/(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})T(?<hours>\d{2})(?<minutes>\d{2})(?<seconds>\d{2})\.(?<microseconds>\d+)Z/)

let match = re.exec(dateString)

let mg = match.groups

let isoDateString = `${mg.year}-${mg.month}-${mg.day}T${mg.hours}:${mg.minutes}:${mg.seconds}.${mg.microseconds}Z`

let myDate = Date.parse(isoDateString)
```

I've been very explicit with each step of the example code for learning purposes, but there are ways to make both the code and the regular expression a bit more terse.

Comment: Thank you, took us some time but thank you again. Have a good day!

Comment: Only the ISO date format is specified as supported format by the specification. You shouldn't use a different format as it can break in other browser or engines or even after an update: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format It would be better to parse the string and use supported values.

Comment: @jabaa Good point.  I've edited my answer to address your valid criticism.